# How to automatically delete elastic search records which are older than 1 month in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have a functionality where I have to delete the elasticsearch records which are more than 1 month old.
I can do it by having a cron job to run the delete query on elastic search, but I want to do that automatically.

Like for S3 file in AWS, I can set TTL. Similarly looking for something like _ttl in elastic search >7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Index lifecycle management](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html) option especially designed to consider these use-cases.

Its also part of basic license so you don't have to buy it, please refer [elastic subscriptions](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions) for more  details.

Comment: These answers are not applicable to the AWS hosted elastic search offering.

Answer (score 1):

For AWS managed ElasticSearch you can use Index State Management (ISM): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/ism.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Posting the complete answer:
1. Create the policy to rollover based on max_age and delete after 10 mins
policy = {
    "policy": {
        "phases": {
            "hot": {
                "actions": {
                    "rollover": {
                        "max_age": "11m"
                    }
                }
            },
            "delete": {
                "min_age": "10m",
                "actions": {
                    "delete": {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

2. Insert the policy:
IlmClient.put_lifecycle(es, "datastream_policy", policy)

3. Create index template to apply policy to all rollover index being created so that they will be deleted after 10 mins:

template = {
    "index_patterns": ["datastream-*"],
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1,
        "number_of_replicas": 0,
        "index.lifecycle.name": "datastream_policy",
        "index.lifecycle.rollover_alias": "datastream"
    },
    "mappings": {
        "email": "keyword"
    }
}

4. Put the index template in elastic search
es.indices.put_template(name="datastream_template", body=json.dumps(template))

5. Create a starter index:
indexd = {
    "aliases": {
        "datastream": {
            "is_write_index": True
        }
    }
}

es.indices.create("datastream-000001", body=indexd)
```